# problem when reusing "LazyTableImages"code

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsurlconnection

i try to reuse the "lazyTableimages" code but i got a problem that the first icons seen didn't get downloaded.I debug and I found that the connection doesn't get a response (only for these icons).

**update** this is the portion of the code which i think is the problem:

```
- (void)startDownload
{
    self.activeDownload = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                         [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.imageURLString]] delegate:self];
    self.imageConnection = conn;
   [conn release];
}
```

and I think that the connection doesn't have enough time to be established.

N.B:i use a custom myUITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i call the method "[tableview reloadData]" from a thread (not the main thread) which will be canceled after that call,so for that reason the connection established to download icons was aborted(when it is called from "..cellForView.." method),so i changed the thread to an an "NSOperation" and i call on it the reloadData method on the main thread which will be like this "`[tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) WaitUntilFinshied:YES];`(syntax need to be verified)

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code in some of my projects. I didn't find any problem in this code. May be you have missed out something else. Have you allocated the Object of IconDownloader ? and call the method startDownload.

Cheers,
Raxit

Comment: hi,(it is me who posted ;))i find a strange probelm:you see the method "- (void)startIconDownload:(AppRecord *)appRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" it calls a method on IconDownloader class.When it is calld ("startIcon..")in "ViewForCell.." method the connection which i talked about before is not established.This problem did not occur when the famous method is called in the method"- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows"!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. That means you are having problem with below statement. Which is in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

[self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath];

Am i right Dingua?

Comment: yes,which calls the nsurlconnection which did'nt have any response.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out something. you are calling [self startIconDownload:appRecord forIndexPath:indexPath]; from (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows and cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Have you print the parameter in NSLog ? check the value of appRecord.imageURLString When you are calling it from cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: it works (i checked the value)until {NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:
                         [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                          [NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.imageURLString]] delegate:self];
}

Comment: after that the connection i think is lost